# NativeScript Unit Testing keep disconnecting

Tags: unit-testing, nativescript, karma-jasmine

Why **tns test** closes blank NativeScript app?

I have initialized a jasmine test from example in Unit Testing NativeScript Docs.

After I run

`tns test android`

First App launches and shows correct test pass screen, but after 4-5 seconds just closes and gives following error in shell.

> DisconnectedClient disconnected from CONNECTED state (transport error)

*All dependencies match the latest package versions :)*

**Things I have already tried**:

1. connecting over wi-fi and USB.
2. two different android mobiles but they closed app after showing successful test screen

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please post the whole code here, but try to cut it down to minimal part necessary to reproduce the problem. Don't post just links to your code! See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example